# Setting a process in startup - non root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, centos, startup

I trying to setup a script in startup (i.e) in ~/.config/autostart/monitor.desktop for linux

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Version=1.0
>   Name=Monitor file
>   Comment=monitor file size
>   Exec=/home/kabali/monitor.py
>   Terminal=false
>   Type=Application
>   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true

when I restart the system and login as kabali the process is not getting started.

/home/kabali/monitor.py is an executable file

Any help is much appreciated!!! Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 1):

If you place that same desktop file in `~/.local/share/`, can you start it manually? Is the `.desktop`-file executable? Does the python-script have a shebang? There are multiple things that could go wrong

I'm not sure starting a python script via desktop entry is a good way to do it. I would suggest using systemd instead, or any other autostart facility. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting for a list of available choices